# INSERT INTO does not honor double quoted column names in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using double quotes in my column names because my source data has fields with the same name but different capitalization. Therefore I am adding double quotes to my column names to distinguish them.

`INSERT INTO ...` does not work in honoring the double quoted column names.

```
create table CAPS_CHECK
(
  "abc" string,
  "ABC" string,
  def string
);

insert into CAPS_CHECK 
VALUES ( 'x', 'y', 'z' );

insert into CAPS_CHECK ("abc")
VALUES ( 'q' );

insert into CAPS_CHECK ("ABC")
VALUES ( 'r' );
```

Everything up to here works as expected (and the `INSERT` was able to distinguish between "abc" and "ABC"), but

```
insert into CAPS_CHECK ("abc", "ABC")
VALUES ( 'a', 'b' );
```

returns

```
SQL compilation error: duplicate column name 'ABC'
```

How can I distinguish between those column names so that I can use them both in the same INSERT statement?

(Note that the same problem happens with `COPY INTO ...`)

Comment: I think this might be a bug.  Worth opening a support ticket with Snowflake.  You could do something like this and have it work, but it's a workaround: `insert into CAPS_CHECK SELECT 'a','b',NULL;`

Comment: while I agree is sounds like a bug, but propagating bad in-house practices also is a bad thing... and would lean towards add underscores

Comment: Related: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009eDNPzSAO/select-column-with-double-quotes and query column name with extra spaces - https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009LG4w9SAD/what-is-the-syntax-in-the-select-statement-to-query-column-name-with-extra-spaces-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-brackets-dont-work-i-imported-a-csv-file-that-has-extra-spaces-in-the-column-names-unfortunately-thanks and https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000090md2oSAA/sql-compilation-error-invalid-identifier